# Converting a string using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string that looks something like this

```
<a href="/team.php?team_id=521">@Arsenal Fc</a> and <a href="/profile.php?fid=50683">@Tester Alpha</a>
```

And I need to convert it to

'#ArsenalFc and Tester Alpha'

three things to keep in mind.

1) for links to the team.php page, The @ is converted to #

2) for links to the team.php page, string spaces are removed (Arsenal Fc to ArsenalFc)

3) for links to the profile.php page, the @ is removed

Any ideas show to do this simply?

Comment: You can first striptags and then use str_replace

Comment: `str_replace('FC Arsenal', 'FC Hansa Rostock', $string);` ;)

Comment: To be honest with you I would parse the string into a `DOM` object and process that.  You may need to wrap it in a dummy `<root>` node to get it to parse, but to me it's easier than trying to use regex for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
function myPregCallback($res)
{
    return '#'.str_replace(' ','',$res[1]);
}
$str = '<a href="/team.php?team_id=521">@Arsenal Fc</a> and <a href="/profile.php?fid=50683">@Tester Alpha</a>';
$newStr = preg_replace_callback('#^.+"/team\.php[^>]+>@?([^<]+)</a>#','myPregCallback',$str);
$newStr = preg_replace('#<a.+?"/profile\.php.+?>@?([^<]+)</a>#','$1',$newStr);
var_dump($newStr); //string(27) "#ArsenalFc and Tester Alpha"
```

This could of course be simpler if the explicit checks for "team.php" and "profile.php" weren't necessary.

Comment: I'm getting an unexpected T_FUNCTION error, on the second line, any ideas?

Comment: @Mortage Yea, sorry - your version of PHP is obviously too low to support anonymous functions (added 5.3) - see updated answer